# Set-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy: Cannot validate argument on parameter 'VaultName'. The argument is null or empty

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-powershell, azure-keyvault

**Trying to Create Premium Key Vault using Azure PowerShell in Visual Studio Code**:

Source Code Reference from [Ned1313](https://github.com/ned1313/Configuring-and-Managing-Microsoft-Azure-Key-Vault/blob/master/m2/M2_Exercises.ps1)-GitHub.

```
#Prefix for resources
$prefix = "cmk"

#Basic variables
$location = "eastus"
$id = Get-Random -Minimum 1000 -Maximum 9999

#Log into Azure
Add-AzAccount

#Select the correct subscription
Get-AzSubscription -SubscriptionName "Test Subscription" | Select-AzSubscription

#Create a resource group for Key Vault
$keyVaultGroup = New-AzResourceGroup -Name "$prefix-key-vault-$id-rg" -Location $location

#Create a new Key Vault
$keyVaultParameters = @{
    Name = "$prefix-key-vault-$id"
    ResourceGroupName = $keyVaultGroup.ResourceGroupName
    Location = $location
    Sku = "Premium"
}

$keyVault = New-AzKeyVault @keyVaultParameters

#Grant yourself access to the Key Vault
# Give your user principal access to all storage account permissions, on your Key Vault instance
$accessPolicy = @{
    VaultName = $keyVault.Name
    UserPrincipalName = "USER_PRINCIPAL_NAME"
    PermissionsToStorage = ("get","list","listsas","delete","set","update","regeneratekey","recover","backup","restore","purge")
}
```

Above Script is worked successfully.

```
Set-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy @accessPolicy
```

**Error**:

`Set-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy: Cannot validate argument on parameter 'VaultName'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.`

If I try replace `Name` with `VaultName` in the block of access policy, such as

`VaultName = $keyVault.VaultName` and the result would be:

`Set-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy: Operation returned an invalid status code 'NotFound'`.

***What would be the cause of the above errors, can anyone help me where I did wrong.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error "***Set-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy: Operation returned an invalid status code 'NotFound***'" occurs if the resource is not found i.e. Key Vault name is not passed correctly or null while executing the script.

When I executed the same script, I got the **`NotFound`** error as below:

[image]

Here the error occurred as the Key Vault is getting created and it is followed by setting by the Access Policy. It needs few seconds of time to be created.

**`New-AzKeyVault`** creates the Key Vault and the value of the **`$keyVault.VaultName`** will be empty because of no gap of seconds between creating Key Vault and setting access policy.

As a **workaround**, you can add **`Start-Sleep -Seconds 2.5`** like below:

```bash
#Prefix for resources
$prefix = "cmk"

#Basic variables
$location = "eastus"
$id = Get-Random -Minimum 1000 -Maximum 9999

#Log into Azure
Add-AzAccount

#Select the correct subscription
Get-AzSubscription -SubscriptionName "Free Trial" | Select-AzSubscription

#Create a resource group for Key Vault
$keyVaultGroup = New-AzResourceGroup -Name "$prefix-key-vault-$id-rg" -Location $location

#Create a new Key Vault
$keyVaultParameters = @{
    Name = "$prefix-key-vault-$id"
    ResourceGroupName = $keyVaultGroup.ResourceGroupName
    Location = $location
    Sku = "Premium"
}

$keyVault = New-AzKeyVault @keyVaultParameters

Start-Sleep -Seconds 2.5

#Grant yourself access to the Key Vault
# Give your user principal access to all storage account permissions, on your Key Vault instance
$accessPolicy = @{
    VaultName = $keyVault.VaultName
    UserPrincipalName = "ruk@xxx.onmicrosoft.com"
    PermissionsToStorage = ("get","list","listsas","delete","set","update","regeneratekey","recover","backup","restore","purge")
}

Set-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy @accessPolicy
```

[image]

[image]

Otherwise, **first create the Key Vault and then set the access policy separately** like below:

```bash
$accessPolicy = @{
    VaultName = $keyVault.VaultName
    UserPrincipalName = "ruk@xxx.onmicrosoft.com"
    PermissionsToStorage = ("get","list","listsas","delete","set","update","regeneratekey","recover","backup","restore","purge")
}

Set-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy @accessPolicy
$accessPolicy
```

[image]

The **Access policy got created successfully** like below:

[image]

Comment: Hey @Rukmini, Thanks for your answer. I got it and also I did a mistake in the code that `User Principal Name` is given as-it-is without changing to User's UPN. Now, When I see your code, caught the ball.